# Question marks instead of actual memory contents in debugger memory view, what does it means?

Tags: debugging, memory, sdk, embedded, xilinx

I am using the Xilinx SDK to debug an application running on a CORA-Z7-10 microcontroller.

When I use the debugger memory view sometimes the view shows the memory as expected, while sometimes it shows a bunch of question marks instead of the actual memory contents.

I know that in that areas of memory there is a binary file and I don't understand why the view shows a bunch of question mark instead. What does these questions marks represent? Why are they there?

To be more clear let's make an example: I put my binaries for the execution at addresses 0x00100000, 0x04000000, 0x08000000 (all in the same DDR3 memory address space). When I stop the execution, let's say at address 0x00101550 (which it is in the first binary), I cannot see memory at 0x04000000 but I can see memory at 0x08000000.
The disassembly view give me an "Memory read error at 0x04000000. Memory read aborted. Fault status 0x8, Domain 0x0". Any clue?

Comment: _"sometimes the view shows the memory as expected, while sometimes it shows a bunch of question marks "_. is that for the same address?  I am not familiar with the architecture or debugger, but it almost certainly means the address is invalid.  On a system with an MMU, the region may not be mapped to the virtual address space.

Comment: Thank you Clifford. There was an MMU problem that prevent the execution, but the memory view problem still remains. I edited the question to be more clear.